# very specific incude errors c++

Tags: c++, include

when i try to include files for in a program i always get `example.cpp: no such file or directory` the only way i can get it working is for `iostream` or if i put `<C:/Users/User/Desktop/C++/CurrentCodeFolder/include/...>` before it.
this can work in some specific cases but usually the files included also have other file they include and these do not work.

is there a way i can fix this so i only need to put `<include/exapleFolder/file.cpp>`?

Comment: You need to set the compiler include directory, but how to do so will vary depending on the compiler you're using and if you're using an IDE or not. You'll need to give us those details or search here since it's very likely someone else has had the problem before. Why are you including cpp files anyway? That's usually a bad idea.

Comment: First, of all one shouldn't include `.cpp` files. Second, use `"`, not `<`/`>`, for including header files local to your project. Third, give the location of the header file relative to the location of the current file. All in all, you need to show a [mre], explain your file hierarchy and how you compile the program. (Also, nothing in your question is specific at all. You are just telling us that you can't include header files without any further details.)

Comment: This is not really a C++ problem but a problem with your build system.